# why navigator storage not work in safari ios

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, blazor, blazor-server-side

i want to show percent of load resources when my blazor wasm site first time load.
this is my solution

```
var myVar= setInterval(function () {
        if ('storage' in navigator && 'estimate' in navigator.storage) {
            navigator.storage.estimate().then(({ usage, quota }) => {
                percent = (((usage / 1024) / 1024) / 21) * 100;
                if (percent > 100) {
                    clearInterval(myVar);
                }
            });
        }

        bar.set(
            percent,     /* target value. */
            true   /* enable animation. default is true */
        );

        
    }, 1000);
```

but this not work in ios safari

[Browser compatibility estimate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OYfz.png)

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: How does the result look like in the working browsers, and how in the IOS safari? Please be more precise with 'this does not work'.

Comment: [StorageManager.estimate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/estimate) *feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.* See **Browser compatibility** on this page.

Comment: @UmairKhan this feature not compatibility in ios safari

Comment: @jasie ios safari not support [estimate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/estimate) 
I did not understand where the question was vague

Comment: It is reported to be available in Safari 17